# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement error C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having an error when I try to create a float and set its value after its created I get this error. I am very confused about what is happening as its the same to the code just above it exept its a float. Heres my code.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sale_Tracker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {       
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string DOW;
        private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DOW = comboBox1.Text;
        }

        int carrotSales;
        float carrotEarnings;
        private void Add1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            carrotSales++;
            carrotEarnings + 1.50; //error is here
            writeTotal1();
            writeEarnings1();
        }

        void writeTotal1()
        {
            total1.Text = "Total: " + carrotSales;
        }

        void writeEarnings1()
        {
            earnings1.Text = "Earnings: $" + carrotEarnings;
        }

        int gAppleSales;
        private void Add2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gAppleSales++;
            writeTotal2();
        }

        void writeTotal2()
        {
            total2.Text = "Total: " + gAppleSales;
        }
    }
}
```

I have already tried adding a `1.50f` in there but it didnt fix it.

Any help would be nice. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: do `carrotEarnings = carrotEarnings + 1.50f;`  or `carrotEarnings += 1.50f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your function Add1_Click as below

```
private void Add1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     carrotSales++;
     carrotEarnings = carrotEarnings + 1.50; //error is here
     writeTotal1();
     writeEarnings1();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have initialised your float variable.

> float carrotEarnings;

And without initialising the value to variable you are trying to increment the variable. Initialise your variable as below.

> float carrotEarnings = 0.0f;

Comment: Did you change the carrotEarnings + 1.50; to carrotEarnings += 1.50f;?